# PHP Stops Parsing Too Soon

Tags: php, parsing, tags

I just switched servers to a server running PHP Version 5.5.9 and Nginx and in the middle of the php code being parsed is this code:

```
$this_page_cats = array ("Examples<br>& Solutions");
```

On this new server, php stops parsing at the '>'  in the '<br>' above instead of waiting until the '?>' that truly ends the code.  I assume there's some simple configuration directive that would correct the problem but I can't seem to find it Googling around.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know that php stops parsing at the '>'? there is some error on the screen? something in your log files?

Comment: everything after the 'br>' is visible on the public webpage and nothing before it is

Comment: Which PHP-Version was it on the old server?

Comment: Maybe an error in the code. An extra quote somewhere earlier, or another similar issue that might have occurred during migration. Maybe you'll see it in an instant when you view the whole file in an editor that has code highlighting. I don't think there is a directive to end strings with a `<`.

Comment: I believe it was 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not PHP stopping parsing, it's PHP not being parsed at all:

e.g. with PHP not working properly, your PHP code is going out to the user's browser AS-IS:

```
<?php
^---start of unknown HTML tag
$this_page_cats = array ("Examples<br>& Solutions");
                                     ^---end of unknown HTML tag
```

Do a "view source" and you'll probably see ALL of your php code.

Comment: hi Marc...I think you're right but the error is gone now so I can't confirm.  I did start off with the page not parsing .htm files for php and after I got that going everything but the above error started working.  I guess I might have just been viewing the pages as my browser cached them before I got parsing going for them...